# EXPORT_SYMBOL macro is giving conflicting types error

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to export a symbol to the kernel. But I am getting the below error. My linux version is 5.4.2,

```
/home/ram/checkout/drivers/char/i2c_sw_hw_common.c: At top level:
/home/ram/checkout/drivers/char/i2c_sw_hw_common.c:1031:14: error: conflicting types  for ‘sfp_i2c_in32’
 UInt32 sfp_i2c_in32(char_dev_t *dev,unsigned int I2cDevaddr, int alen, unsigned int offset,unsigned int I2cAddr,int Width, int AccessType)
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/ram/checkout/drivers/char/i2c_sw_hw_common.c:3:
/home/ram/checkout/drivers/char/i2c_sw_hw_common.h:123:8: note: previous declaration of ‘sfp_i2c_in32’ was here
 UInt32 sfp_i2c_in32(char_dev_t *dev,unsigned int I2cDevaddr, int alen, unsigned int offset,unsigned int I2cAddr,int Width, int AccessType);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/ram/checkout/drivers/char/i2c_sw_hw_common.c: In function ‘sfp_i2c_in32’:
/home/ram/checkout/drivers/char/i2c_sw_hw_common.c:1035:18: warning: unused variable ‘byte_count’ [-Wunused-variable]
    unsigned int byte_count = 0 ;
              ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/ram/checkout/drivers/char/i2c_sw_hw_common.c: At top level:
/home/ram/checkout/drivers/char/i2c_sw_hw_common.c:1063:29: error: conflicting types for ‘sfp_i2c_in32’
 EXPORT_SYMBOL_NOVERS(sfp_i2c_in32);
                         ^~~~~~~
In file included from /home/ram/checkout/drivers/char/i2c_sw_hw_common.c:3:
/home/ram/checkout/drivers/char/i2c_sw_hw_common.h:123:8: note: previous declaration of ‘sfp_i2c_in32’ was here
 UInt32 sfp_i2c_in32(char_dev_t *dev,unsigned int I2cDevaddr, int alen, unsigned int offset,unsigned int I2cAddr,int Width, int AccessType);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
```

Here is my declaration, definition and export of this symbol.

i2c_sw_hw_common.c

```
UInt32 sfp_i2c_in32(char_dev_t *dev,unsigned int I2cDevaddr, int alen, unsigned int offset,unsigned int I2cAddr,int Width, int AccessType)
{
    // code
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(sfp_i2c_in32);
```

i2c_sw_hw_common.h

```
UInt32 sfp_i2c_in32(char_dev_t *dev,unsigned int I2cDevaddr, int alen, unsigned int offset,unsigned int I2cAddr,int Width, int AccessType);
```

Comment: While the error message shows identical signatures for the declaration (in the header) and the definition (in the source file), it could be **different meaning** of types used in that signatures. E.g. between including the header and defining the function it could be something like `#define UInt32 int` in your source file. So in the header return value is `unsigned int`, but in the source it is `int`.

Comment: BTW, the title "EXPORT_SYMBOL macro is giving conflicting types error" is wrong: it is not `EXPORT_SYMBOL` which causes the **primary** (first) **error**.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you would re-define your types such as `Uint32` if the kernel already defines `u32` (and similar) in `<linux/types.h>`?  As Tsyvarev mentioned this could be one way the signatures differ.  Try changing that across and see if the error still happens.

Comment: Yeah, that was the issue. I have used `-save-temps` flag and saw the preprocessed output. in the definition the `UInt32` was translated to `unsigned int` but the declaration still remained `UInt32`. need to check why it happened. But for now, I have removed `UInt32` from both the places and replaced it with `unsigned int`. Thanks alot.

Comment: @Andy J, Actually this piece of code is part of a large driver code and I am not sure of the reasons for specifying user-defined typedef `UInt32` in the driver code.

Comment: If you have the time, could you answer your own question with the solution you found?  This will help future readers.  Thanks!

Comment: yeah sure. Will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the use of user-defined data types. Instead of `unsigned int`, I have used `UInt32`, which is user-defined.

```
typedef unsigned long UInt32;
```

This usually does not create any problem as long as you have the same definition visible in both the header file and the source file.

But in my case, in the source file(.c), `UInt32` got treated as a macro and expanded as `unsigned int` after preprocessing is done.

But in the header file, `UInt32` was still a user-defined datatype. So the compiler threw the above errors.

I got to know about this after examining the preprocessor stage output (use `-save-temps` flag for this).

After the preprocessor stage, the declaration remained as,

```
UInt32 sfp_i2c_in32(char_dev_t *dev,unsigned int I2cDevaddr, int alen, unsigned int offset,unsigned int I2cAddr,int Width, int AccessType);
```

But the definition was changed to,

```
unsigned int sfp_i2c_in32(char_dev_t *dev,unsigned int I2cDevaddr, int alen, unsigned int offset,unsigned int I2cAddr,int Width, int AccessType)
{
    // code
}
```

So, removed all the user-defined datatypes from my code and used only predefined ones.

The minimalistic example for above issue can be this,

```
// file.h
typedef unsigned long UInt32;

UInt32 f();



// file.c
#include "x.h"

#define UInt32 unsigned int

UInt32 f()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Error you would get,

```
x.c:6:14: error: conflicting types for ‘f’
 UInt32 f()
        ^
In file included from x.c:2:0:
x.h:3:8: note: previous declaration of ‘f’ was here
 UInt32 f();
        ^
```